# TFS get <file> removes pre-existing local copies of <file>

Tags: tfs

I'm porting a legacy VSS-based build script to TFS. The script gets files from several server locations into different directories... to make this work with the same structure in TFS I frequently map & unmap specific working folders.

This seemed to work, until the script gets the same server file into two different local folders. Even though previous working folders are un-mapped, TFS moves the existing copy of the file rather than getting a second copy.

e.g:

1. cd dir1
2. tf workfold /map $/SOME_PATH .
3. tf get file.abc /all
4. tf workfold /unmap .
5. cd..\ dir2
6. tf workfold /map $/SOME_PATH .
7. tf get file.abc /all
8. tf workfold /unmap .

On line 7, I get "Replacing file.abc (moved from c:\dir1)" and end up with only one copy of file.abc.

I'm aware our process is not TFS-friendly but right now I just want it working so we can drop VSS, and then focus on re-structuring afterwards. Is there a way to stop this behaviour or a workaround I could use that doesn't totally change our process?

Comment: Can you use two workspaces?  One workspace for each directory would avoid this problem.

Comment: No. Things get copied all over the place so I'd need loads of WS and to keep track which was used where ;) Not really practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this in TFS. if you remove a workspace mapping it'll remove the files. If you try to map the same file to 2 places you'll get an error.

You need to fix your build process. A short term solution might be to get the file once and then copy it to any other locationsit is needed. otherwise I think you need to bite the bullet and refactor your build process to be simpler. regardless of what systems you are using, simplifying you're build will help you in the long term.

Comment: "if you remove a workspace mapping it'll remove the files" It doesn't remove files... it moves them if a previous `get` put them in a different workfolder. I'm not sure if that's what you meant, it read like you were saying the act of removing a mapping would cause the files to be deleted at that time, which is not the case.

Comment: @John it does, in fact, remove them if you remove the mappings and don't add new ones.  In your case, it optimizes that to be a move.

Comment: I mean that if you change the mapping, the next time you "get", TFS will update your workspace copy of the code to match what it thinks you should have - if you move the mapping, the file "moves". If you delete the mapping so that the file is not mapped anywhere, the file will be deleted. Of course, you can change mappings and say "no" when TFS asks if you want to "get" to update everything so that the files on disk are not immediately affected, but the change will still take place the next time you "get" to update your workspace.

Comment: That's clearer Jason... it deletes them _next time you get_ after removing the mapping - removing the mapping itself doesn't afect your local files.

Comment: Correct. If you change the mapping in the UI, it asks if you want to update your workspace to reflect the changes, and if you accept the default option it does an immediate get.

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm trying to get multiple versions of a workspace folder and put them into two separate locations. I should be able to tell TFS not to keep moving things around. This is either a bug of extremely poor design in TFS.

Comment: Why would it try to move things around even after you've unmapped the folder? That makes no sense.

Comment: @MikeCollins sounds like you need to create a retrospective branch, which will allow you to map an older version of the files in the branch to a different location.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to get this working fast:

1. Cd Dir1
2. tf workfold /map $/SOME_PATH
3. tf get file.abc /all
4. **Copy file.abc to temp location**
5. tf workfold /unmap
6. cd..\ dir2
7. tf workfold /map $/SOME_PATH
8. tf get file.abc /all
9. **Copy file from temp location to dir1**
10. tf workfold /unmap

Comment: Yeah I'm considering doing a more complete `get` to a temp location first, like a "local repo" and then modifying the scripts so each time I see a `get` I instead do a copy.

Comment: I would do that as well  except that we are working with some really large work folders containing thousands of files, which would drastically increase the time required for the script to run. I ended up doing a rename instead and it seemed to work. On the next "ft get", TFS said it was moving the files but didn't because I had renamed the original folder so TFS couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found no answer online so I figured out the solution and wrote up a blog post: http://www.softwarepronto.com/2013/09/getting-multiple-labels-from-tfs-using.html.

If you don't want to read the blog, the solution is to create the workspaces in different directories (see below):

```
MKDIR D:\ATest

CD /D D:\ATest

tf workspace /delete WorkSpaceATest /noprompt

tf workspace /new WorkSpaceATest /noprompt

tf workfold /map $/ATest D:\ATest /WorkSpace:WorkSpaceATest

tf get /version:LATest01

MKDIR D:\BTest

CD /D D:\BTest

tf workspace /delete WorkSpaceBTest /noprompt

tf workspace /new WorkSpaceBTest /noprompt 

tf workfold /map $/BTest D:\BTest /WorkSpace:WorkSpaceBTest

tf get /version:LBTest01
```